# How can i add javascript files into an existing web page with firefox add on sdk

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am toying around with the firefox sdk add on right now, and I want to add javascript files to an existing website - like adding jquery to an existing website.

How do I do that?

Comment: do you own the website page? or is this a 3rd party website?

Answer (score 1):

There are some solutions to do that. One example is the following:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
    var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: [
            data.url("jquery.min.js")
        ]
    }); 
});
```

Where the `jquery.min.js` is in your data folder of your extension and it will attached to the active tab.

One other solution is to use `pageMod` that it will allow you to determine in which web pages the JS will attached. In the following example it will attached to mozilla.org.:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("my-script.js")
});
```